# Philosophical Investigations Part one and two

Tags: wittgenstein

I was wondering how is the book "Philosophical Investigations" by Ludwig Wittgenstein split? I have read that there are part one and part two. It may sound stupid but I have the "critical-genetic edition" and I am not aware of a splitting.

I have read so far, that the first 315 paragraphs are the first part.
So my question(s) is: what is part one/two and how does it relate to the critical-genetic edition and why do we speak about part one and two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed two parts. The first part ends with paragraph 693. See [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein/#PhilInve):

> Philosophical Investigations was published posthumously in 1953. It was edited by G. E. M. Anscombe and Rush Rhees and translated by Anscombe. It comprised two parts. Part I, consisting of 693 numbered paragraphs, was ready for printing in 1946, but rescinded from the publisher by Wittgenstein. Part II was added on by the editors, trustees of his *Nachlass*. In 2009 a new edited translation, by P. M. S. Hacker and Joachim Schulte, was published; Part II of the earlier translation was here labeled “Philosophy of Psychology – A Fragment” (PPF).